# How to change or upgrade the version of Node.js and npm in a Meteor app without updating Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

Meteor is typically behind in Node.js version because it is a framework that uses its own bundled version of Node.js, and its APIs and features are built to rely on that version of Node.js.

I'm sure that in many cases upgrading Node.js poses no problem.

As an example, Meteor 2.10 at time of writing ships with Node.js 14. But we're already on Node.js 19.

---

Is there a way to tell Meteor (f.e. with the `meteor` cli, or some meteor package) to use newer versions of Node.js (and npm)?

Answer (score 2):

**Meteor 1.4** now supports **Node 4.4.7**!
[See release notes](http://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#v14)

#### To upgrade to Meteor 1.4:

- Go to the root of your project's directory
- `meteor update`

Comment: I had to run `meteor update` twice. First time, it just updated Meteor from 1.3.x to 1.4.3.1. Second time, it updated the Node and NPM versions.

Comment: Current node V is `v13.12.0` I've ran `meteor update` and it's only updating node to `v12.16.1` is there anything I can do to upgrade meteor's node further or do I need to downgrade meteor?

Answer (score -1):

Meteor does not support NodeJS 4+ as of now. The discussion is available in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5124

The latest update to the thread on April 29 is:

> Guys, relax. The difference between Node version 4, 5 and 6 are relatively minor, and so if Meteor can support one, it can and will support all others. Ben created PRs for every currently active and supported Node version, but the fundamental part of the work is about making Meteor work with any (recent, non-legacy) Node version, and from there basically everyone should be able to freely select whichever one fits their goals and intentions best (i.e. 4.x if you don't care for bleeding edge Node, 6.x if you do; 5.x is not going to stick around for very long as it's not an LTS version).
>
> So come and check out and help with the PRs if you're interested and
>   you can, but if not, just rest assured this is being worked on and
>   prioritized appropriately and I'm pretty sure Ben (and/or others
>   working on this) will keep everyone posted on any meaningful progress.